# Redirect .htaccess to different page on different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I tried searching for similar posts but none of them satisfied my need. Hence I have to ask a new question

I have some domain space on my university website like this `<university>.edu/~<myname>` which is actually `<university>.edu/~<myname>/index.html`

I want all the traffic from here to go to `<myname>.wix.com/resume`. But I don't want other pages like my `<university>.edu/~<myname>/somethingelse` to redirect anywhere.

Also I want the address bar to still show  `<university>.edu/~<myname>` even when it has readirected to my site on wix.com.

Kindly let me know if this is possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No browser that I know of will allow itself to be redirected to a different site, without displaying the URL of the new site in the address bar.  However, there are ways that you can display content from `<myname>.wix.com/resume` on your page at `<university>.edu/~<myname>/index.html`.  One way is to use a frame (or an iframe) on `<myname>.wix.com/resume` which would load content from `<university>.edu/~<myname>/index.html`.  Another (perhaps more seamless) solution would be to use a server-side scripting language (such as PHP) to create a script at `<university>.edu/~<myname>/index.php` which would download the content 'on the fly' from `<myname>.wix.com/resume` and display it at `<university>.edu/~<myname>/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used iframe to get my wix website show up on my university page. I think this is the only best option if you don't want the url in the address bar to change